# Socket.io - Only Emit to Certain Users?

Tags: socket.io

Forewarning, I am very new to Node.js and Socket.io and this probably has a simple answer.

I am using it in conjunction with a PHP app. The intention is to have real-time notifications.

If you take a scenario such as Facebook -- something with lots of users, but the notifications should only be sent out to certain sets of users, how do I target those users?

I've thought of setting something like:

```
socket.on('notification-[user_id]', function() {...} );
```

But that would be insane considering thousands of users.

It also seems to be insane to send notifications to thousands of users and have each user have to figure out whether it's for them or not.

Is there a way around this? What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe what you need is more Server-Side Event than socket.io. If you only want to push things like notifications, no need to set bi-directionnal communication. To send to some users in socket.io, either you handle this in your code with a table, or you can use the room feature or namespace.

Comment: I am going to look into Server-Sent Events -- that looks like it could be what I need. I'm also going to look into the room feature/name spaces, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm new to them too, but i think you can do it like this:
In the client side you can just:

```
socket.on('notification',function(){...});
```

In the server side you can use :

```
io.sockets.connected[socketid].emit('nofification',data);
```

Hope it can help you~